# How to generate local SDP on Python without

Tags: websocket, webrtc, sdp

I'm creating an application with Python to simulate a WebRTC client a/v connection. I'm at the stage where i need to generate the local client's SDP to send to the remote server.  I've done some searches on the internet and most of the results points to using java script. Is there a way to do this on Python without Java scripting?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [aiortc](https://github.com/jlaine/aiortc) a try, it is a Python WebRTC implementation.